# Django Complicated Query

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am using django restframework with my Django app and I need to create quite specific query.

Here is the models.py:

```
class TaskHours(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hours = models.FloatField()
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
```

views.py:

```
class TaskHoursView(generics.ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = TaskHoursSerializer
   queryset = TaskHours.objects.all()
   
   def get_queryset(self):
       start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
       end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
       return TaskHours.filter(date__range=[start_date, end_date])
```

and serializer is default one with class Meta with all fields.

This query is working fine but I need to alter it. In the data there are entries which have same name and same date, but different tasks. What I would need is get all the tasks and hours worked with the same name and date to one object like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "date": "2021-04-14",
    "task": "cleaning",
    "hours": "4.5",
    "task": "hoovering",
    "hours": "2.0"
}
```

Now I am receiving it like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "date": "2021-04-14",
    "task": "cleaning",
    "hours": "4.5",
},
{
    "name": "John",
    "date": "2021-04-14",
    "task": "hoovering",
    "hours": "2.0"
}
```

Is there any way how to merge the two objects into one?

Comment: Your use case implies your schema is not normalized. Considering your use case `task` and `hours` should be in a _separate_ model that has a `ForeignKey` to `TaskHours`.

Comment: I understand that, but I am receiving the data from already existing database, so I cannot update it.

Comment: The JSON you expect is not valid. You can not have 2 "task" fields inside the same object. The closest you can get is having a single "tasks" field which would be a list.

Comment: @Guillaume That would be helpful too. Any idea how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slightly modify your serializer in order to create a subquery for each object you're going to serialize.

```py
class TaskHoursSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tasks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = TaskHours
        exclude = ['task', 'hour']

    def get_tasks(self, obj):
        tasks = TaskHours.objects.filter(name=obj.name, date=obj.date).values_list("task", "hour")
        return list(tasks)
```

And also, you need to change the queryset in your view in order to not have object duplicates.

```py
class TaskHoursView(generics.ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = TaskHoursSerializer
   queryset = TaskHours.objects.all()
   
   def get_queryset(self):
       start_date = self.request.query_params.get('start_date')
       end_date = self.request.query_params.get('end_date')
       return TaskHours.filter(date__range=[start_date, end_date]).values('name', 'date').distinct()
```

That should output a field called "tasks" containing each task with the matching hour.

Comment: The output is exactly what I wanted, thank you. However the transaction take a lot of time (around 2 mins). Is there any way how to make it faster?

Comment: With this code, you do a subquery for each instance of Taskhours so it takes a lot of time. But with the design of your DB, I really don't see any other way of doing it (e.g. using `prefetch_related` or `select_related`). IMO, you can just use this kind of workaround.

Comment: @pipikej You can try overriding the `to_representation` and using `itertools.groupby`. You would just need to make sure the queryset is ordered. (Although the preferred solution would be to fix the database schema)

Comment: So, as per your use case this is the only way you can do it, otherwise to make it fast you have fix your database design, as of now it is redundant.

You have to split `TaskHours` model into two different model where one model  contain `name` and `created` and other one `task`, `hours`, `foreign key with first model`. In this way you will also removed duplicated values of name and created and after that you can use `prefetch related` that will take hardly more than 2 queries to perform the same action you need.